# Packer provisioning with ansible fails in yandex cloud

Tags: ansible, centos, cloud, devops, packer

I'm trying to create image with `Packer` in yandex-cloud on my local CentOS machine.
Packer uses `Ansible` provisioner and runs playbook containing the role.

Packer template:

```json
{
    "variables": {
           "zone": "ru-central1-a",
           "instance_cores": "2"
       },
    "builders": [
       {
           "type": "yandex",
           "service_account_key_file": "{{user `service_account_key_file`}}",
           "folder_id": "{{user `folder_id`}}",
           "source_image_family": "{{user `source_image_family`}}",
           "image_name": "reddit-db-base",
           "image_family": "reddit-base",
           "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
           "platform_id": "standard-v1",
           "zone": "{{user `zone`}}",
           "instance_cores": "{{user `instance_cores`}}",
       "use_ipv4_nat" : "true"
       }
   ],
   "provisioners": [
       {
           "type": "ansible",
           "playbook_file": "../ansible/playbooks/packer_db.yml",
           "extra_arguments": ["--tags","install"],
           "ansible_env_vars": ["ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=../ansible/roles"]
       }
   ]
}
```

Ansible playbook:

```yaml
- name: Installing MongoDB
  hosts: all
  become: true
  roles: 
    - db
```

However, during process I am getting the below error:

```
...
==> yandex: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> yandex: Connected to SSH!
==> yandex: Provisioning with Ansible...
    yandex: Setting up proxy adapter for Ansible....
==> yandex: Executing Ansible: ansible-playbook -e packer_build_name="yandex" -e packer_builder_type=yandex --ssh-extra-args '-o IdentitiesOnly=yes' --tags install -e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/tmp/ansible-key647683404 -i /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible030511675 /home/ansible/playbooks/packer_db.yml
    yandex:
    yandex: PLAY [Installing MongoDB] *******************************************************
    yandex:
    yandex: TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
    yandex: fatal: [default]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory.In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo /root/.ansible/tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1614119638.2707298-11423-111899549529332 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1614119638.2707298-11423-111899549529332=\"` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1614119638.2707298-11423-111899549529332 `\" ), exited with result 1", "unreachable": true}
    yandex:
    yandex: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    yandex: default                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
...
```

How can I fix the issue? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by adding the user in section `provisioners` of Packer template:

```json
"provisioners": [
       {
           "type": "ansible",
           "user": "ubuntu",
           "playbook_file": "../ansible/playbooks/packer_db.yml",
           "extra_arguments": ["--tags","install"],
           "ansible_env_vars": ["ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=../ansible/roles"]
       }
]
```